# Inferring $d$ in $dx$ as derivative?

Tags: integration, notation

For few problems now, I've made substitutions by inferring $d$ in $dx$ as derivative.

An example is in the proof of

$$\int_a^bf(a+b-x)dx=\int_a^b f(x)dx$$

where one notes that "if we infer $d$ as derivative", then

$$-d(a+b-x)=dx$$

and we can write

$$\int_a^bf(a+b-x)dx=-\int_a^b f(a+b-x)d(a+b-x)$$
$$=-(F(a)-F(b))=F(b)-F(a)=\int_a^b f(x)dx$$

This "inferring" seems legit, but is it and what's it that I'm really doing here with the $d$?

Comment: What is basically going on is this: https://upload.wikimedia.org/math/7/1/f/71f79f0ede7f450e53e21dd64e444e6f.png

Comment: What you write is basically a mnemonic for it. For details, you can refer to: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution#Substitution_for_single_variable

Answer (score 1):

First note that
$$\int_a^b f(x)\ \mathrm dx=\int_a^b f(t)\ \mathrm dt$$
Since the function and the limits are equivalent, then the variable of integration that we use does not affect the result. Now for your integral we have
$$\int_a^b f(a+b-x)\ \mathrm dx$$
Using $u$-substitution, we have
$$u=a+b-x\Rightarrow -\mathrm du=\mathrm dx$$
Which implies that
$$-\int_b^a f(u)\ \mathrm du=\int_a^b f(u)\ \mathrm du=\int_a^b f(x)\ \mathrm dx$$
Therefore
$$\int_a^b f(a+b-x)\ \mathrm dx=\int_a^b f(x)\ \mathrm dx$$

Comment: How is $\int_a^b f(u)du $ "the same as" $\int_a^b f(x)dx$, you just said $u=a+b-x$ i.e. may be $u \not = x$.

Comment: @mavavilj: The variable just after the $d$ is called a "bound variable": it can be renamed and the statement still holds. It's just a label that is eventually thrown away. The area under the curve doesn't change whether you're in the $xy$-plane, the $uy$-plane, or even the $\psi y$-plane since the variables are just arbitrary names.

Comment: @Deusovi What is confusing is the reuse of an already bound variable. Surely $x=x$, but why $x=a+b-x$ for all $a,b>0$?

Comment: @mavavilj The variable is bound _inside_ the integral and has no communication with the variables inside (or outside) other integrals. The $u$-substitution acts only inside one integral. It does _not_ assert that the $u$ inside one integral is equal to $a + b - x$ inside another integral.

Comment: @DavidK, +1, very clear explanation.